# smooth (Lon, Lat, Value) data over shapefile

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, spatial-interpolation, spatial-data

I am trying to plot a data with (Lat, Lon) and a value in each location. What I need to do is to plot the data over a shapefile, represent each value with a different color,  and smooth the values, so no gaps occur in the map.

The data has the following structure: (Longitude, Latitude, Value), could you help me please.

I know how to plot the data over a shapefile with a different color, but the issue is in smoothing the values.

The data for the question is available in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bOpWjPoYc0Ix1cQqA73iFr-by0J1wU5l

where the:

1- (Lon, Lat, Value) data is in csv file "cluster__groups"

2- The shapefile files are in the folder "shapefile_question"

I ned to show them in regions. The output should be something similar to the following picture:

[image: output_result]

Thank you for your help. I tried to solve and search for a solution but could not find a solution, so pardon me if this is a discussed topic.

Best regards,
Moe

Comment: You mention you want to plot the data over a "shapefile". A shapefile is a vector file... are you sure you didn't mean to plot the data on a *Raster* file, rather than a vector one like the shapefiles? Rasters with coordinates and values are commonly known as DEMs

Comment: no, I want to plot them over a shapefile. As in my question, I have the points (Lon, Lat, Value) and a shape file, and I want to plot the data to appear as a regions instead of points with gaps in locations with no information

Answer (score 2):

I will post a solution with some guidance, since there was no code posted. It seems that what you are after is **how to perform spatial interpolation with R**. You have your points divided into four categories and you want to create regions out of them. For this, there are a number of different approaches, and I will list three of them, easiest to hardest:

1. [Nearest neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation);
2. [Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting);
3. [Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging).

All of these techniques are available in R, and you can find a nice set of examples [here](http://rspatial.org/analysis/rst/4-interpolation.html). Keep in mind that these three techniques will give you slightly different regions, and sometimes they are combined in order to produce an "ensemble" of the most likely surfaces.